# Files are copied twice from first and second level folders

Tags: c#, file, copy, enumeration

I have found and remastered the following code to my needs. The code copies all spreadsheets from a source folder to a new folder based on an enumeration of spreadsheet file extensions.

However, it copies files twice (bug!), if they are in the source folder or subfolder of first level. Any other subfolders at second or third levels are only copied once, as intended.

What is the bug?

A second question, you see in the enumeration it has code to skip directory. I have tried deleting this code, because it does not seem necessary, and deleting the code does not affect the outcome. Is it necessary?

```
string argument1 = @"C:\Test";
string convert_directory = @"C:\Test";
// The input and output directory must be identical for the error to happen
           
if (argument3 == "Recursive=Yes")
            {
                var extensions = new List<string> { ".fods", ".ods", ".ots", ".xls", ".xlt", ".xlam", ".xlsb", ".xlsm", ".xlsx", ".xltm", ".xltx" };

                // Create enumeration that only includes spreadsheet file extensions
                var enumeration = new FileSystemEnumerable<FileSystemInfo>(argument1,(ref FileSystemEntry entry) => entry.ToFileSystemInfo(),new EnumerationOptions() { RecurseSubdirectories = true })
                {
                    ShouldIncludePredicate = (ref FileSystemEntry entry) =>
                    {
                        
                        // Skip directories (is this necessary?)
                        if (entry.IsDirectory)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        // End of skip directories

                        foreach (string extension in extensions)
                        {
                            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(entry.FileName);
                            if (fileExtension.EndsWith(extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                // Include the file if it matches extensions
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        // Doesn't match, exclude it
                        return false;
                    }
                };

                // Copy spreadsheets based on enumeration
                foreach (var file in enumeration)
                {
                    // Rename new copy
                    int copy_file_number = 1;
                    string new_filepath = convert_directory + "\\" + copy_file_number + file.Extension;
                    while (File.Exists(new_filepath))
                    {
                        copy_file_number++;
                        new_filepath = convert_directory + copy_file_number + file.Extension;
                    }

                    // Copy
                    File.Copy(file.FullName, new_filepath);
                }
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Every file on every level was copied exactly once. If there's a bug, it's not within the code you posted. Or I'm missing information. Maybe you accidentally execute your code more than once?

Comment: Thanks @marsze. It made me recheck my debugging. See my answer for debugging.

Comment: If you `ToList` the enumeration first then it should work even on the same input/output folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input and output folder are the same.

So you need to cache the list of files to copy before beginning the actual copying. Simply change the `foreach` line to do this.

It also seems sensible to keep the `copy_file_number` between loops so you don't have to keep checking the same files.

```
int copy_file_number = 1;
foreach (var file in enumeration.ToList())
{
    // Rename new copy
    string new_filepath = Path.Combine(convert_directory, copy_file_number + file.Extension;
    while (File.Exists(new_filepath))
    {
        copy_file_number++;
        new_filepath = Path.Combine(convert_directory, copy_file_number + file.Extension);
    }

    // Copy
    File.Copy(file.FullName, new_filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @marsze for rechecking my code and confirming it works. It made me think more about my debugging.

I used the same input directory as output directory. Then this error happens. If directories are different, it doesn't. Ideally this shouldn't be an issue, because files should only be copied once irregardless of what folder level, theey are in.

But my solution will be to make sure the input and output parameters cannot be identical.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).